# Why does SO block creating a tag "column" for the Unix "column" command?

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation-process, plurals

I'm trying to tag my question with "column", which is the Unix command. SO says "the tag columns already exists". Notably, SO says the plural, whereas the Unix command is singular.

Is this a bug?

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Probably both are banned for having been (ab)used in an excessively-broad way / not being a single topic that someone would be interested in following. Don't worry, not every topic in your post needs to be a tag.

Comment: In fact, `columns` is on the list of **268** tags I keep dead every day.  Even if you could create it, it would have been promptly removed because of the abuse it's seen.  In fact, this might have been the only historical legitimate use of the tag *ever*.

Comment: @Charles Really? Can I see the list?

Comment: @bjb568 Here's the list as of the other week when I last regenerated the bookmarklets.  I'm due for another round soon. http://pastebin.com/p0kN64wE  The list is composed of bag (abused) tag names, tag names that happen frequently that are spelled differently (`angularjs` vs `angular.js`, `zend-framework2` vs `zf2`, etc), and burninated tags that I keep an eye on just in case.

Comment: @Charles Thanks for the info. I understand. Is there a suitable way to tag using a specific Unix command, such as "column(1)" or "column-the-unix-command" or some such?

Comment: I'd personally consider 'column' to be too broad. Instead I'd use [tag:unix-column].

Answer (score 4):

What is a problem about a column supposed to be? CSS? Some command? Your neighbor's roof (supported by columns) is falling down? This tag is too vague, that's probably why it's been banned.

Rule of thumb: if you can't be an expert in the tag, it shouldn't exist. You can't be a "column-expert", you can be a "unix-commands" expert. You *might* be able to be a "column-command" expert, but it's probably too specific.

Comment: Is [tag:tr] too specific?

Comment: I thought a tag is a keyword or label that categorizes the question with other, similar questions (in my case, the "column" command which I agree is a vague/overloaded word). Is there a way to do "column(1)" to make it match the Unix command man page doc?

Comment: @icktoofay, no, but it's unfortunate that *nobody every reads tag wiki excerpts* resulting the constant abuse of that tag...  Trust me, `column`/`columns` is *worse*.

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson, tags are not keywords.  Each tag is supposed to have a specific, narrow definition and use case.  See [this old blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).  Things that are *generic* terms, like "column" and "columns" end up having multiple definitions and uses, making their use as tags entirely useless due to abuse by people that can't read.

Comment: @Charles: Yes, I, too, am almost certain [tag:column] would be worse; I was merely commenting on the assertion that “you *might* be able to be a ‘column-command’ expert, but it's probably too specific”.